# xml parsing in c++ using tinyxml

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, tinyxml

i am creating xml file in c++
i wrote the code like creating writing the xml file in c++ as shown below

```
const char* assign =

    "<?xml version=\"1.0\"  standalone='no' >\n"
    "<office>"

    "<work>file created</work>"
    "</office>";

TiXmlDocument doc( "vls.xml" );
        doc.Parse( assign );

    if ( doc.Error() )
        {
            printf( "Error in %s: %s\n", doc.Value(), doc.ErrorDesc() );
            exit( 1 );
        }
        doc.SaveFile();


    bool loadOkay = doc.LoadFile();

    if ( !loadOkay )
    {
        printf( "Could not load test file 'vls.xml'. Error='%s'. Exiting.\n", doc.ErrorDesc() );
        exit( 1 );
    }
    else
        printf(" 'vls.xml' loaded successfully");
```

but now i need only the data in the XMl file not the tags
guys plz help me.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest reading the [TinyXml documentation](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html), more specifically the [TiXmlElement documentation](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlElement.html).

For your special case, I'd say it looks like that:

```
TiXmlElement * office = doc.FirstChildElement( "office" );
if( office )
{
   TiXmlElement *work = office.FirstChildElement( "work" );
   if( work )
   {
       printf("Work text: %s\n", work.GetText());
   }
}
```

Although I'm not an expert with TinyXml.

FYI:

- [StackOverflow search function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tinyxml)
- [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789817/how-to-use-tinyxml-to-parse-for-a-specific-element) - [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166757/help-me-with-tinyxml) - [You](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531694/how-to-obtain-the-value-from-an-xml-tag-using-firstchildelement) - [should have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521404/parsing-xml-elements-using-tinyxml) - [considered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888694/parsing-multi-path-literal-not-measured-in-tinyxml) ....

*Please, search **Google** and **StackOverflow** before asking such trivial questions.*